# I have deployed sample nginx app in k8s and configured istio but using istio gateway ip I could not able to access the application outside

Tags: kubernetes, istio

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: test-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: test-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - test-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /test-charts

    route:
    - destination:
        host: test-charts
        port:
          number: 9080
```

**Note:** But i could able to access the application with LB ip

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-100-164:~/istio-1.9.0$ kubectl get svc
NAME          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
test-charts   LoadBalancer   10.0.101.148   20.62.141.231   80:31480/TCP   6h19m
```

Comment: Please some one help me in the above issue!. Thanks advance.

Comment: Checkout istio docs: [Determining the ingress IP and ports](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports). It explicitly mentions the following command: `kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system` to use to determine IP of an istio ingress gateway LB. Try using this addresss to connect.

Comment: In case you get 404 response from nginx, change `uri.exact: /test-charts` to `uri.exact: /` and try again.